# jquery ajax delete request deletes some but not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, express, server

This is a school assignment. I created a server with express and an app with jquery. Instead of using a database, it is writing jsons to a file.

It's like Twitter, but it's called Chirper and each html paragraph is like a tweet, but called a "chirp". I created a delete button for each chirp that sends an ajax delete request to the server. The button is working on some chirps, but not on others. By working, I mean, that the json chirp is deleted from the json file. What is the bug that prevents every delete button from working?

I've copied my app.js file here first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

let chirps = [];
let user;
let text;

// handle API request (api call below) the server responds with a nested object of chirps
function handleResponse(data) {
    // change object into array of objects
    let entries = Object.entries(data)
    // destructure entries array & extract user & text to chirps array
    for (const [number, chirp] of entries) {
        chirps.push(`${chirp.user}: ${chirp.text}`);
    }
    // remove 'nextid' element in array
    chirps.pop();
    // map over array, 
    chirps.map((chirp, index) => {
        // get a timestamp for each chirp
        let time = (new Date().getTime())
        // create a delete button for each chirp, set class
        let x = $('<button>x</button>').attr('class', 'delete');
        // create a paragraph containing each chirp
        let p = $(`<p>${chirp}</p>`).attr({
            // set a class for styling
            class: "chirps",
            // set a timestamp key (referenced by 'id' in server methods) for deleting/updating later
            key: `${time}`
        }).append(x);
        // append each paragraph to div
        $('.current').append(p)
    })
}

// use get request to call api
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps').then(handleResponse).catch(err => console.log(err));      // or use localhost:3000

// on submit button click, get the value of user inputs and ...
$('#submit').click(() => {
    user = $('#user').val();
    text = $('#text').val();
    // make a post request with those values
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "user": `${user}`, "text": `${text}` })
    })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

// on delete button click
$(document).on("click", ".delete", event => {
    // set variable for the button's parent (the chirp)
    let chirpToDelete = $(event.target).parent()
    // remove html chirp from display
    chirpToDelete.remove()
    // also send delete request to remove from server
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps/${chirpToDelete.attr('key')}`
    })
        .then(() => console.log(`deleted chirp ${chirpToDelete.attr('key')}`))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

})

And my server.js file next:

```
const fs = require('fs');               // import file system
let chirps = { nextid: 0 };             // keep track of chirps

if(fs.existsSync('chirps.json')) {      // check for existing chirps file
    chirps = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('chirps.json'));    // if already there, read the file and set chirps count to that file
}

let getChirps = () => {                 // calling getChirps will return all the chirps
    return Object.assign({}, chirps);   // Object.assign creates a copy to send back to protect from manipulation
}

let getChirp = id => {                      // getChirp with id returns copy of one specfic chirp
    return Object.assign({}, chirps[id]);   
}

let createChirp = (chirp) => {              // createChirp creates a chirp with next available id
    chirps[chirps.nextid++] = chirp;        // saved in chirps object
    writeChirps();                          // call function to write the chirp (below)
};

let updateChirp = (id, chirp) => {          // pass in id & chirp to update existing
    chirps[id] = chirp;
    writeChirps();
}

let deleteChirp = id => {                   // delete a chirp with specific id
    delete chirps[id];
    writeChirps();
}

let writeChirps = () => {               // chirps written to json
    fs.writeFileSync('chirps.json', JSON.stringify(chirps));
};

module.exports = {                  // export each (no need to export writeChirps because it is for this file only)
    CreateChirp: createChirp,
    DeleteChirp: deleteChirp,
    GetChirps: getChirps,
    GetChirp: getChirp,
    UpdateChirp: updateChirp
}
```

Comment: Also, you have a logic error in your delete logic, as you are using the index of the element to determine which one to delete.  Consider the following.  You have 5 chirps.  You delete the 4th chirp.  Now your json file has 4 chirps.  Now you try to delete the chirp with index 5.  But there are only 4 chirps in the file.  You cannot reliably use indexed based mappings to associate the chirps on the front to the chirps in the file.  You need some other form of identifier that will match, regardless of if the index changes.  Edit: this is assuming you are using an array.

Comment: @Taplar, I'm working through your answers. For first one, does this look right: `$(document).on("click", ".delete", event => {
        // set variable for the button's parent (the chirp)
        let chirpToDelete = $(event.target).parent()`

Comment: Yeah, that should accept the event in on the arrow function that is the event handler.

Comment: Had already verified the index matches the deleted chirp but when I made corrections for `.then(() => {console.log(...` after delete, the console log does not match the deleted chirp, so there's the problem. Any suggestions for another form of identifier besides index? I am using an array.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I might say, give each one of the chirps a create timestamp, in milliseconds.  You could use that as the identifier that you pass around to know which one to delete.

Comment: I changed 'id' to 'key' and set a timestamp on each chirp. I removed the server's json file that held the chirps for a fresh start and created more chirps. I console logged the timestamps after deleting, and they matched. However, the ajax delete request is not working; no chirp is getting deleted on the server's json file but the .then is still calling back with the correct timestamp. Now I'm searching stack for 'ajax delete request not working' ...

Comment: Um, perhaps I didn't explain this well enough.  `let time = (new Date().getTime())`  You are generating a timestamp for the chirp when you display it on the page.  Displaying a chirp on the page, is not when the chirp is created.  The chirp is created when it is inserted into the JSON file.  The JSON file needs to have the create timestamp on each chirp.  When you retrieve the chirps from the server, that request needs to return the timestamp with each chirp, and the client just attaches the returned timestamp to the associated chirp.  So the timestamp in the JSON matches the chirp on the page

Comment: oh! got it. I wasn't exactly sure where to put it, but that makes sense. Thanks for sticking with a newbie for this one!

Comment: When I went back to complete this, the delete request was still not functioning. I took a deeper look at the delete method in the server, which was provided by the teacher. It deletes a chirp by index -- the object index! I didn't quite understand before that objects had indices and that you could access them that way. Posted the code I ended up with, feel free to critique it.

Comment: Does the code you posted work, or do you still have issues?

Comment: seems to be working well, no issues. I'm guessing because the id of the object isn't a true index, just an id and isn't giving me the index problems I had before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

let chirps = [];
let user;
let text;

// handle API request (api call below) the server responds with a nested object of chirps
function handleResponse(data) {
    // change object into array of objects for iteration
    let entries = Object.entries(data)
    // destructure entries array & extract user, text in an object to chirps array
    for (const [id, data] of entries) {
        chirps.push({
            "user": `${data.user}`,
            "text": `${data.text}`, 
            "id": `${id}`
        });
    }

    // remove 'nextid' element in array
    chirps.pop();
    // map over array, for each object in the array ...
    chirps.map(chirp => {
        // create a delete button for each chirp, set class
        let x = $('<button>x</button>').attr('class', 'delete');
        // create a paragraph containing each chirp, set a class for styling, set id with timestamp, append a delete button to each paragraph
        let p = $(`<p>${chirp.user}: ${chirp.text}</p>`).attr({
            class: "chirps",
            id: `${chirp.id}`
        }).append(x);
        // append each paragraph to div
        $('.current').append(p)
    })
}

// use get request to call api
$.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps').then(handleResponse).catch(err => console.log(err));      // or use localhost:3000

// on submit button click, get the value of user inputs and ...
$('#submit').click(() => {
    user = $('#user').val();
    text = $('#text').val();
    // make a post request with those values
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "user": `${user}`,
            "text": `${text}`,
        })
    })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

// on delete button click
$(document).on("click", ".delete", event => {
    // set variable for the button's parent (the chirp)
    let chirpToDelete = $(event.target).parent()
    // remove html chirp from display
    chirpToDelete.remove()
    // also send delete request to remove from server
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: `http://122.0.0.1:3000/api/chirps/${chirpToDelete.attr('id')}`
    })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

})